# object db is not a member of package play

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to make my first tests with Scala and with Play framework.

I have installed play 2.2.0, which seems to be the last version, with the standalone package. After that, I've been able to create a new application, compile and run it.

I've tried to start to use Anorm package to access to the database, but I've found a blocking error which I can't find on the docs. I don't know if that means that is so obvious, but after adding:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.db.anorm._ //(this is the new line)

object Application extends Controller {
  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }
}
```

It fails with:

> object db is not a member of package play

I've seen this:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/RUbmEVsw2rY/UOE5mNs1WjoJ

Where they talk about adding the dependency to jdbc, which seems to be already in my build.sbt.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache
)
```

I've also found this thread here:

- [play.db package not found in play 2.1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696156/play-db-package-not-found-in-play-2-1-3)

But I can't find a build.scala file on my project. Not using any IDE by now, just play console (run & compile commands).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you by chance defining your own `package play`? That would shadow the Play framework.

Comment: Thanks, but no:(. I've edited the post to include how the controller's file looks like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact (as the error explains), there is no package `play.db.anorm._` in version 2.2.0. Try use `import anorm._` instead.

Comment: Thanks Yall, that was all. Seems that part of the docs/tutorials still have references to the previous import.

Answer (score 1):

You need the following libraries

```
slick
play-jdbc
anorm
```

This is how my dependencies look like in `build.sbt` :

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.slick" % "slick_2.10" % "2.1.0",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41",
  "com.typesafe.play" % "play-jdbc_2.10" % "2.4.0-RC1",
  cache,
  anorm
)
```

Search for the latest version of library at [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org)